# Troubleshoot Ubuntu 16.04 app startup

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, startup, startup-applications

I have a script in my home directory which opens Google Chrome with certain parameters when I start the system. I have 12 different machines that use the same configuration. However, the startup application works 10-12 times out of 12. The script doesn't start on at least one of my machines, while not specifcally on a single one of them. It rotates totally randomly.
I have no idea how to troubleshoot the problem. I can't find any logs related to this behaviour.

This is my setup:

rw-rw-r-- /home/user/.config/autostart/start-tabs.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Start Chrome Tabs
Comment=Start Google Chrome tabs
Exec=/home/user/chrome-tabs.sh
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

rwxr-xr-x /home/user/chrome-tabs.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30
nohup google-chrome --kiosk --disable-infobars 'https://example.com'
```

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot and fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `nohup`, the output of your command is dumped in a log file. To quote its man page:

> If  standard  input is a terminal, redirect it from an unreadable
>   file.   If standard output is a terminal, append output to 'nohup.out'
>   if possible,'$HOME/nohup.out' otherwise.  If standard error is a
>   terminal, redirect it to standard output.  To save output to FILE, use
>   'nohup COMMAND > FILE'.

This means that both stdout (normal output) and stderr (error output) from chrome should be logged in `~/nohup.out` (because your script is in `~` - other people: the nohup.out file will be in your executable directory, or `~` if executable directory is not writable).

Since your problem sounds like a race condition (chrome sometime starting up before everything it needs is ready), you'll probably find useful info in this file.